# Redirect to another content provider

Tags: android, apk, android-contentprovider, telephony

Everyone knows that Facebook reads user's SMS-content on Android. Me tasked to create fake Content Provider and redirect Facebook to read fake SMS database.

I'm trying to create my own content provider to replace default Telephony on Android, which will handle Facebook's requests separately.

So, there are two questions:

1) Where can i find complete project of TelephonyProvider? Decompilation of TelephonyProvider.apk has no good results.

2) How can i handle requests of specific app separately in content provider?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Me tasked to create fake Content Provider and redirect Facebook to read fake SMS database.

Fortunately, this is not possible, for blindingly obvious privacy and security reasons, unless you control the device firmware.

> I'm trying to create my own content provider to replace default Telephony on Android

Fortunately, this too is not possible, for blindingly obvious privacy and security reasons, unless you control the device firmware.

> Where can i find complete project of TelephonyProvider?

http://source.android.com.

> How can i handle requests of specific app separately in content provider?

You can see if `Binder.getCallingUid()` returns something that identifies the app that invoked the `ContentProvider` -- I do not know if that works or not.